# How can i know version of zookeeper

Tags: apache-zookeeper, apache-storm

I'm new to `storm` and `zookeeper` , i imported project and want to know version of `zookeeper` that the coder used ! as he mentioned that he used `storm-0.8.2` but didn't talk about `zookeeper`

Is there anyway to know version of `zookeeper` he used from specific folder of the project

Comment: I don't think Storm is dependent on certain versions of Zookeeper. I've always just used the most recent one, but I haven't read anywhere that Storm requires a specific Zookeeper version. Though you might want to follow a more recent tutorial. storm-0.8.2 is pretty old. Use this example with the newest versions of Storm + Zookeeper should work fine. https://storm.apache.org/tutorial.html

Comment: i imported project using storm-0.8.2 and i have to run it as the coder first then i'll try to run with newest version , but is there anyway to know which version coder used from project folder ? or for example after mvn package the project maybe i'll know ?

Comment: If you're using mvn, you can use the `mvn dependency:tree`, that should allow you to see what version of libraries are packaged in your jar. Other than that, I guess it really depends on what is in your project folder. It's hard to tell without further information.

Comment: ok then if i use any version of zookeeper with storm-0.8.2 there is will no problem with that ?

Comment: I can't guarantee there won't be a problem with it, but in my 6+ months of working with Storm I've never read that storm version x.x.x needs Zookeeper version x.x.x. So I'm not really sure what will happen. The only way to find out would be to test it yourself. Which also seems like the only option you have left to.

Comment: ok i'll try thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is no hard dependency to zookeeper in storm. you may use any version of zookeeper with storm, configuring zookeeper and storm configuration files, zookeeper.conf and storm.yaml

Answer (score 0):

Came across this question while searching for the very same thing!
If you want to run the exact same version of Zookeeper server that matches the Zookeeper Java client version that your version of Storm uses, the best way I found is to check the POM file for Storm parent, and search for the `<zookeeper.version>` tag under the `<properties>` tag:

1. If you are integrating Storm libraries with your own Java application using Maven, the simplest way to get this is via your local Maven repository, after your first build:
   *nix:
   `~/.m2/repository/org/apache/storm/storm/${STORM_VERSION}/storm-${STORM_VERSION}.pom`
   Windows:
   `%USERPROFILE%\.m2\repository\org\apache\storm\storm\%STORM_VERSION%\storm-%STORM_VERSION%.pom`
2. If not, you can get it from the Storm GitHub sources for the latest Storm version:
   `https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/master/pom.xml`
3. Finally, to find the same as 2. but for a previous Storm version, you can get the zip/tarball from GitHub for that version, then look inside the root of the extracted folder for the pom.xml file.